# How to calculate gauge sizes?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to create a converter for this chart:

https://ww2.riogrande.com/content/brown-sharpe-gauge-thicknesses-cg-html

I have written the cm to inch part to three decimal places:

```
function LengthConvertermm(valNum) {
    document.getElementById("inputinch")
    .value=parseFloat(valNum*0.03937007874).toFixed(3);
}
```

But on the chart, the higher the measurement, the lower the gauge number!
How would I create this part of the code? I can't work it out as it doesn't seem as simple as multiplication!

Comment: do you have an example of what you want? from mm to gauge?

Comment: @NinaScholz yes the first link shows the mm - inch - gauge examples, and so far I have made this: https://jsfiddle.net/sgpascoe/8f0ywvg7/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge), gauge sizes are mathematically well defined.
Therefore, gauge sizes in inches and in mm can easily be calculated from the gauge number, simple arithmetic gives the reverse results as well.

Note that I've floored the results (not rounded) for in and mm results, as the table you linked to did the same.

```js
const gaugeToIn = n => 0.32486 * Math.pow(Math.E, -0.11594 * n);
const gaugeToMm = n => 8.25154 * Math.pow(Math.E, -0.11594 * n);
// Unused, but reverse operations as well
const inToGauge = n => Math.round(Math.log(n / 0.32486) / (-0.11594));
const mmToGauge = n => Math.round(Math.log(n / 8.25154) / (-0.11594));

// Used to display results
const write = msg => {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('p')).innerHTML = msg;
};

for (let gauge = 0; gauge < 35; gauge++) {
  const flooredIn = gaugeToIn(gauge).toFixed(3);
  const flooredMm = gaugeToMm(gauge).toFixed(3);
  write(`gauge ${gauge}: ${flooredIn} in / ${flooredMm} mm`);
}
```

Comment: Amazing! The top two lines are the math I need! How would I reverse the conversion?

Comment: @user2436271 [The logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) is the inverse operation of the exponent, I've added the example to the answer.

Comment: Incredible, thanks so much! This was my finished conversion widget! https://jsfiddle.net/sgpascoe/8f0ywvg7/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
function LengthConvertermm(valNum) {
    document.getElementById("inputinch").value= 100 - parseFloat(valNum*0.03937007874).toFixed(3);
}
```

// assuming 100 is the maximum number

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
parseFloat(+valNum*0.03937007874)
```

Maybe  `valNum` is string;

Comment: The mm/inch part is done, it's the gauge part I'm struggling with.

I have written this 

https://jsfiddle.net/sgpascoe/8f0ywvg7/4/

but 10 Gauge is supposed to be 2.59mm and 20 gauge is 0.812mm